# How to get data from DataFrame include multiple dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I have following type of DataFrame structure.**

```
   0                                  1                                  2  
0  {'A': 5, 'B': 0, 'C': 7, 'D': 9}  {'A': 6, 'B': 7, 'C': 2, 'D': 8}  {'A': 2, 'B': 8, 'C': 6, 'D': 3}
```

**Output I am looking for:**

```
My dataframe is of number dictionaries in the columns 

    A    B    C    D
0   5    0    7    9
1   6    7    2    8
2   2    8    6    3
```

`code`
I don't have much idea about to solve this type of DataFrame structure

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(list(df.values.ravel()))`?

Comment: how you creating the dataframe?

Comment: I am not creating DataFrame here. I have to get data from DataFrame as shown in my input

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang, Its working fine.

Answer (score 6):

You can do [`squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.squeeze().tolist())

   A  B  C  D
0  5  0  7  9
1  6  7  2  8
2  2  8  6  3
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
s = df.T[0].apply(pd.Series)
```

or

```
s = pd.DataFrame(df.T[0].tolist(),index=df.columns)
Out[162]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  5  0  7  9
1  5  0  7  9
2  5  0  7  9
```